# XCode: Labels on top of image disappearing in custom table cell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a custom table cell where two labels are on top of an image, though are not appearing when I run the app in the simulator. When I comment out the image, I see the labels just fine.

I have auto-layout set, pinning the image to the top, bottom, left, and right of the super view. I also have the labels pinned to left and right edges of the superview, and vertical spacing between them and the bottom edge of the superview to the bottom label.

If the image is included, however, I don't see the labels at all. I'm sure they're above (i.e. they come after) the image in the scene explorer at the left.

Any ideas? Here's what the custom cell looks like:

[image]

I've tried deleting all constraints, running without using Auto-layout at all, re-adding constraints several times... nothing seems to work.

My UITableView class is as follows:

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cardImage: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func setProperty (name: String, location: String, cardImageName: String) {

    self.name.text = name
    self.location.text = location
    self.cardImage.image = UIImage(named: cardImageName)

}
```

}

I've also done println in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, and the name and location are populating properly from the array... which I already knew, as they populate properly when the image is commented out. Maddening!

Here's how the labels and image are stacked:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you maybe debug the frames of the labels, to see if they are actually there or not? Do you have any code in your custom UITableViewCell class that might influence that?

Comment: Hi Caterina, I'm not sure exactly how to debug the frames of the labels, but when I comment out the image line in the function that sets the name, location and image in the UITableViewCell class, the name and location show up fine. I've added that class above.

Comment: Put a breakpoint somewhere that you know the view is being displayed. Then in the debugger console, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` to get a print out of all the views.

Comment: Have you tried to add the image first, then the two labels?  The last three lines of your setProperty function, try card image first line then the labels next two lines.

Comment: The image is on top of the labels, the labels are there beneath the image, you just can't see them.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I just tried that, and got the same result. @sasquatch, I thought maybe as much, but I've double-checked that the image is underneath the two labels. I've added a screenshot of the scene explorer above.

Comment: Here's the weird thing: I just added a View between the image and the labels, and now it's all showing up. Totally bizarre. I guess it's sort of fixed... but not really, as I still have no idea why that was happening. Seems possibly like a bug, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: hudsonian, In your image where you show the labels and images are stacked, I am wondering if you actually drag the labels above the image view would they show.  So instead of Content View, Image View, Name Label, Location Label.  It looks like this....  Content View, Name Label, Location Label, then Image View.  Maybe when you put the view in between, it forced the labels to the top.  Just a thought, this is an interesting question.

Comment: It's a really weird one. The labels actually disappeared again, even with the view in between. I've tried dragging them on top in the scene explorer, and that definitely seems to put them underneath in the simulator. I made the image 50%, and the labels are there, so they're being placed underneath the image, but the question is why. I've put the image first in the setProperty function, I've moved everything in different configurations in the stacking view of the explorer on the left... and it seems like this must simply be a bug of some sort, as there's no other explanation I can figure out.